# How can I Deserialize a RSS?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, deserialization

This is my code:

```
var objectText = XmlReader.Create(requestedURL);
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InstagramItems));
var instagramItems = (InstagramItems)mySerializer.Deserialize(objectText);
```

but seems it can't work with RSS (which are "XML more or less"):

```
Server Error - <rss xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

How can I do it? I believe there are .NET library without using 3rd part plugins.

Part of the RSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Photos tagged as "example" on Instagram</title>
  <link>http://instagram.com</link>
  <description>Photos tagged as "example" on Instagram</description>
  <atom:link href="http://instagram.com/tags/example/feed/recent.rss" rel="self" />
</channel>
```

Comment: Could you please post a piece of the XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Download the RSS XSD : http://www.thearchitect.co.uk/schemas/rss-2_0.xsd

Step 2: Use xsd.exe to generate an RSS type based on the schema

Step 3: If objectText is only an RSS document, then just substitute your newly created RSS type for InstagramITems in the above code.

Step 3a: If the object text is mixed Instagram and RSS code, then use the DataContractSerializer and pre-register both Instagram and RSS types with the DataContractSerializer before attempting to deserialize

Comment: I get RSS from an external resources, I can't manage it! I just download and process...

Comment: You're not changing the RSS xml. You're using the xsd to generate a c# type that the rss can be deserialised to, in this case RssItem.

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer works with specific xml format, if you suply any other format other then which it expects the metioned exception will be throwned.

You can parse the xml manualy and create InstagramItems from the parsed xml, I would recommed using linq to xml here is an example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e38e69ac-d325-4cc4-bdf7-bc940e19e63f/read-xml-and-create-objects-using-linq